# I need to make a favorite button and change the image when click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I create a button with a star image and I need do change the image when clicked. Like when click the button makes favorite and when click again remove favorite.

here's the code

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}
favButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[favButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stardes.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
favButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 90, 20, 25);
[cell.contentView addSubview:favButton];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: set it's image to the new image in buttonClicked ?

Comment: but this aproach won't work because when the cell gets redrawn it will redraw with the original image again. You need to keep a list of 'favourited' index paths and when you layout the cell choose and image based on whether that index path has been 'favourited'

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the state somewhere. It is usually stored in an array (yourdataset) indexed by the indexPath, which I noticed that you don't use. In addition to change the image on click, you will need to set the state in the array.
In the buttonClicked method, iterate the superView until you reach the UITableViewCell of the clicked button, find the position in the table. Now you have the index of the data in the array to be changed.

After that, just check the state before set the background image. Something like this:

```
MyData* dta = self.myData[ indexPath.row ];
if (dta.favorite)
    [favButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stardes.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [favButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stardes2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```